# Python Multiprocessing on Selenium objects IN ONE BROWSER WINDOW... possible? (Chrome; example inside)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, multiprocessing, webdriver

quick rundown of what I want to do:

1. open website via selenium
2. gather many objects from it (in this case it's 200 js checkboxes)
3. click them all **AS QUICKLY AS POSSIBLE**, which would entail engaging all my processor's cores, so  that each core is responsible for approximately a quarter of the objects (since I have 4 cores)

I've already written the code so that it works like a charm WITHOUT multiprocessing.

So, if I want to use MP, the plan right now is to roughly do this:

```
import selenium_operations as sop 
#^separate file in which I've defined some selenium-related functions 
#related to mining stuff from a webpage

from multiprocessing import Process

if __name__ == '__main__':

    boxes = sop.getBoxes(selection) #get the boxes. There's 200 of them

    box_set_1 = Process(target=sop.clickBoxes, args=(boxes[0:50],))
    box_set_2 = Process(target=sop.clickBoxes, args=(boxes[50:100],))
    box_set_3 = Process(target=sop.clickBoxes, args=(boxes[100:150],))
    box_set_4 = Process(target=sop.clickBoxes, args=(boxes[150:200],))
    
    box_set_1.start() #click the boxes
    box_set_2.start()
    box_set_3.start()
    box_set_4.start()
    
    box_set_1.join()
    box_set_2.join()
    box_set_3.join()
    box_set_4.join()
```

Look good? Or is tere something I should be aware of?

p.s. am using Chrome

Comment: the webdriver communicates via wire protocol to the browser.  It's sequential... do this, then this.  However, you can execute javascript which would run in the browser async.  This is just clicking DOM elements... no need for multi-processors/threads here... just non-blocking js calls.  Those clicks may or may not happen at the same time.  Not sure the browser's made to support multiple-mice.... but maybe multiple fingers??

Comment: Please do expound? What javascript method would I need to employ?
(also, this doesn't exactly answer my question, but... ok, continue...)

Comment: Javascript click: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click  In selenium use webdriver.execute_script(your_javascript)  Build your script as a string.  So to do this all async just get all the elements and click them in your javascript using async methods.

Comment: So basically the browser will decide how many cores or threads to use... I think they're generally pretty good at that.  You just send async javascript for the browser to run which won't block any particular thread.

Comment: well, thanks for the info, but I guess I also have to ask:
Will this async execution work on Selenium objects? Don't forget that I DID use Selenium to gather the objects, and as such, their type is non-JS.

Comment: And another question: Would I need to redefine the python function for clicking the squares to be a js function instead?

Comment: yes, I believe you can use webelement references that Selenium returns for the JS.  So you could use find_elements to return an array of the elements and then pass those into your script string.  (I don't know python, but I believe I've seen code posted here that does pass the reference directly in...)  find_elements might even perform as async... I guess you'd have to time the two to find out which is quicker if speed is your concern.  2) Yes you need a string which is the javascript.

Comment: You might "believe" so, but I've yet to find examples or evidence. All my personal improvisation attempts have failed so far lol

Comment: you won't need to do it that way.  Just find the element references in your JS.

Comment: I did try to do it that way, but after gathering the elements via
    var squares = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
I couldn't get them to click. squares[whatever].click(); does nothing, as does squares[23].addEventListener("click", function() {});

Comment: Start a new thread/question with the code that's not working.  In general, though, I wouldn't expect you to save all that much time... maybe 1 second tops. (vs using standard webdriver methods)